# Capture event that creates all views on adding models to the existing collection backbone marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have implemented the following functionality:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'app',
    'views/y/x/FlightScheduleLayoutView',
    'collections/y/x/ScheduleCollection'
], function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, App, FlightScheduleLayout, ScheduleCollection) {
    var FlightScheduleListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        collection: ScheduleCollection,
        itemView: FlightScheduleLayout,
        doSort: function(sortCode, sortDirection) {
            this.collection.setSortField(sortCode, sortDirection);
            this.collection.sort();
            this.collection.trigger('reset');
        },
        onAfterItemAdded: function(itemView) {
            if ($(itemView.el).hasClass("flight")) {
                var flight = $(itemView.el);
                var flightDetailsBtn = flight.find(".flight_details");
                var flightDetails = flight.find(".option_details");
                var count = parseInt(this.children.length);
                var flightDetailsId = "flight-details-" + count;
                flightDetailsBtn.attr("data-target", "#" + flightDetailsId);
                flightDetails.attr("id", flightDetailsId);
                flight.find("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
            }
        }
    });
    return FlightScheduleListView;
});
```

Now there is a functionality somewhere in js that does the following:

```
this.flightScheduleListView = new FlightScheduleListView({ collection: schedules });
```

Add later in code this happens:

```
this.flightScheduleListView.collection.add(this.flightSchedules.models.slice(this.numberOfFlightSchedulesVisibleCurrently, this.numberOfFlightSchedulesVisibleCurrently + this.flightSchedulesPerPage));
```

Using `OnAfterItemAdded` works perfectly. But this is time consuming as it iterates over every view. Is there any render function that gets called when we add something to the collection of the view? I can't use `OnRender` because it's only called on View instantiation and not when adding to collection.

Comment: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#onaddchild-callback

Comment: I have  looked up the documentation, Couldnt find any, that could handle gets triggered when multiple childviews are appended. Because OnAfterItemAdded is getting called for each item.

Answer (score 0):

**onAddChild callback**

This callback function allows you to know when a child / child view
instance has been added to the collection view. It provides access to
the view instance for the child that was added.

```
Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  onAddChild: function(childView){
    // work with the childView instance, here
  }
});
```

References :
http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#onaddchild-callback

Comment: This too is at child level. I was wondering if we have something to capture all children in one go. Not at each child level. But All children.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get. What do you mean by `child level` ? This comment negates your comment in the question.

Comment: I just meant that , the solution you suggested captures each childview and then works on it. Is there a way to capture all childview in one function in one iteration?